# Python : Atom error message "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'E:\\Erangi\\IIT_Project\\WebSite\\Churn"

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, atom-editor

I am trying to connect my database to the SQL server. But I get the following error when I run

```
python
from appT import db
```

It works perfectly fine when I run the "python appT.py" command.

Note: The overall code worked perfectly fine when i first ran the program. This error occurred when i re-run the program after some time.

The following code is saved as appT.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pickle
import numpy as np
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql

model = pickle.load(open('logreg.pkl', 'rb'))  # read mode

app = Flask(__name__)  # initializing Flask app

                                                         #usenaw:password
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:''@localhost/customer'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

if __name__ == "__main__":

 db = SQLAlchemy(app)

 class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(30))
    district = db.Column(db.String(100))
    make = db.Column(db.String(100))
    age = db.Column(db.Numeric(50))
    value = db.Column(db.Numeric(100))
    usage = db.Column(db.String(100))
    fuel = db.Column(db.String(100))


    def __init__(self, gender, district, make , age, value, usage, fuel):

        self.gender = gender
        self.district = district
        self.make = make
        self.age = age
        self.value = value
        self.usage = usage
        self.fuel = fuel

@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('indexT.html')

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
      if request.method == 'POST':
        gender = request.form['gender']
        district = request.form['District']
        make = request.form['Make']
        age = request.form['veh_age']
        value = request.form['veh_value']
        usage = request.form['Usage']
        fuel = request.form['Fuel']

      #Data encoding for predicting
      if request.method == 'POST':
        d1 = request.form['gender']
        if (d1 == 'Male'):
            d1 = 1
        else:
            d1 = 0
        d2 = request.form['District']
        if (d2 == '5. Colombo District'):
            d2 = 0
        elif (d2 == '7. Gampaha District'):
            d2 = 1
        elif (d2 == '10. Kalutara District') :
            d2 = 1
        elif (d2 == '14. Kurunegala District') :
            d2 = 1
        elif (d2 == '24. Ratnapura District') :
            d2 = 1
        elif (d2 == '11. Kandy District') :
            d2 = 1
        elif (d2 == '6. Galle District') :
            d2 = 2
        elif (d2 == '23. Puttalam District') :
            d2 = 2
        elif (d2 == '12. Kegalle District') :
            d2 = 2
        elif (d2 == '3. Badulla District') :
            d2 = 2
        elif (d2 == '2. Anuradhapura District') :
            d2 = 2
        else:
            d2 = 3
        d3 = request.form['Make']
        if (d3 == '10.HONDA'):
            d3 = 0
        elif (d3 == "17.MARUTI"):
            d3 = 1
        elif (d3 == "21.MITSUBISHI"):
            d3 = 2
        elif (d3 == "22.NISSAN"):
            d3 = 3
        elif (d3 == "24.SUZUKI"):
            d3 = 4
        elif (d3 == "26.TOYOTA"):
            d3 = 5
        elif (d3 == "European_veh"):
            d3 = 6
        else:
            d3 = 7
        d4 = int(request.form['veh_age'])
        if ( d4 >= 1 and d4 <= 5):
            d4 = 0
        elif (d4 >= 6 and d4 <= 10):
            d4 = 1
        elif (d4 >= 11 and d4 <= 15):
            d4 = 2
        elif (d4 >= 16 and d4 <= 20):
            d4 = 3
        else:
            d4 = 4
        d5 = int(request.form['veh_value'])
        if ( d5 > 0 and d5 <= 1000000):
            d5 = 0
        elif (d5 > 1000000 and d5 <= 2000000):
            d5 = 1
        elif (d5 > 2000000 and d5 <= 3000000):
            d5 = 2
        elif (d5 > 3000000 and d5 <= 4000000):
            d5 = 3
        elif (d5 > 4000000 and d5 <= 5000000):
            d5 = 4
        elif (d5 > 5000000 and d5 <= 6000000):
            d5 = 5
        elif (d5 > 6000000 and d5 <= 10000000):
            d5 = 6
        else:
            d5 = 7
        d6 = request.form['Usage']
        if (d6 == '01.PRIVATE'):
            d6 = 0
        else:
            d6 = 1
        d7 = request.form['Fuel']
        if (d7 == '01.PETROL'):
            d7 = 1
        elif (d7 == '02.PETROL_HYBRIDE'):
            d7 = 2
        elif (d7 == '03.DIESEL'):
            d7 = 3
        else:
            d7 = 0

        #Data base store
        my_data = Data(gender,district,make,age,value,usage,fuel)
        db.session.add(my_data)
        db.session.commit()

       #Model predicting
        arr = np.array([[d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7]])
        pred = model.predict(arr)

        if pred == 0:
            return render_template('indexT.html', prediction_text="Churn Customer")
        else:
            return render_template('indexT.html', prediction_text="Retained Customer")
      else:
        return render_template('indexT.html')

#app.run(host="0.0.0.0")            # deploy
app.run(debug=True)                # run on local system
```

Comment: Add `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the `app.run` line, and indent the `app.run` line.